# Why my UITextField data is lost when we come back from Second view controller to main view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have three view controllers (first, second and third view controllers), first view controller and second view controller has 4 `UITextField` each one, after entering the data in text fields we can go from one VC to another along with data, finally we display data in third VC. The problem is when we come back from second to first the textfield is no more there. Not sure why this happens? How to solve this problem? Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: are making textfield empty in viewwillapper or in viewdidload ?

Comment: sorry i con't understand..

Comment: are you making textfield empty in viewwillappear  or in viewdidload of 'FC' ?

Comment: i ma using NSUserDefaults class to store the data and display the data in a label in final View controller. If we come back text field data not visible.

Comment: you should put check in viewWillAppear that nsuserdefaults have the value or not if it has a value then you should put it back in textfield. :0

Comment: Can you show some code? What actually you are trying?

Comment: Is it compulsory to put back data in text field ....

Comment: is there any other way....

Comment: If you're pushing SecondVC from FirstVC, then data should remain in the textField unless and until you are clearing the text or setting @"" to textfield in viewWillAppear: method of FirstVC.

Comment: Could you please show the code currently you are using?

Comment: In viewDidLoad:                                                             self.firstNameTF.delegate = self;
self.lastNameTF.delegate = self;
self.ageTF.delegate = self;

Comment: @VadlaniMarking: It would be great if you could edit the question and add the code over there. Also, please do add the code for viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear method.

Answer (score 1):

when you push or present a new `UIViewController` you can send data with it but as soon as you reach the second `UIViewController` your first `UIViewController` releases the space from phone hence all your data in previous screen is lost.

and the only option you have is to send back the data you send while coming to second `UIViewController` and you can do it is by simply creating delegate class to send data.

create a header file lets say Sample.h and create this method inside it you can choose the datatype you want.

```
- (void)secVCDidDismisWithData:(NSDictionary *)data;
```

import header file in second `UIViewController` in .h file and put this line of code there

```
@property (nonatomic, assign)   id<Sample> delegate;
```

then you have to make custom pop button or dismiss button and put this code

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
if(_delegate && [_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(secVCDidDismisWithData:)])
{
    [_delegate secVCDidDismisWithData:@{@"key1":@"value1",@"key2":@"value2"}];
}
```

then on the first `UIViewController` .m file import your second `UIViewController` which I am sure you already have done to present or push the screen then just below that add put this line

```
@interface FirstVC () <Sample>
```

and then create the object of second `UIViewController` and set delegate to self and the implement the delegate method you made like this

```
- (void)secVCDidDismisWithData:(NSDictionary *)data{
     NSLog(@"%@",data);}
```

Comment: The data will be lost only in case viewcontroller is popped from navigation stack. In case that firstviewcontroller pushes secondviewcontroller, then view controller will remain in navigation controller's stack